# Creating trigger with 'instead of delete'

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I want to treat a delete statement as an update but it throws this error, and I don't know what it means.

```
create or replace trigger Miembros_V_IOD
   instead of delete on Miembros_V 
   for each row
Begin
   update Miembros set (end_date = sysdate)
   where Miembros.nick = :old.nick
   and Miembros.club = :old.club;
end;

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------
2/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/34     PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis around `end_date = SYSDATE`.

Comment: @Del it does not work

Comment: @Del at first it didn't work but it was because I had put the name of a table wrong, then it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pointing to the `=` sign. You're getting a PL/SQL error - albeit one caused by the inner SQL - and for a trigger the line numbers in PL/SQL errors start from the `DECLARE` (if you have one) or `BEGIN`, *not* from the start of the overall `CREATE` statement. So the `2/34` refers to character 34 of the second line of the PL/SQL part, which is:

```
   update Miembros set (end_date = sysdate)
```

... which is the `=`.

You shouldn't have the parenthesis around `(end_date = sysdate)`:

```
create or replace trigger Miembros_V_IOD
instead of delete on Miembros_V 
for each row
begin
    update Miembros set end_date = sysdate
    where Miembros.nick = :old.nick
    and Miembros.club = :old.club;
end;
/

View MIEMBROS_V created.
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfdc1a54af2202c9fe47ce36ddd75780)

The syntax diagram [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5) shows that parentheses can go around a list of columns on the left-had side of the equals sign, or around a subquery on the right; but not around the whole `set` clause. Because you have `set (end_date` it's expecting that to either have a comma or closing parenthesis next, i.e. `set (end_date) = ...` - hence the ORA-00907 being thrown when it didn't see that.